# How do I save the contents of an ASP.MVC View to a string?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to save the HTML output of an ASP.MVC 3 View() as a string that I can send to another web service. When I call "return view()" it obviousy renders the output to the screen. I just want to capture that to a string of HTML. Possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ViewContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.viewcontext.aspx) to have the MVC framework render the view to a TextWriter class like [StringWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stringwriter.aspx) then retrieve the rendered string from that object.

```
public string RenderViewToString(ControllerContext context, ViewResultBase viewBase)
{
    using (var sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        var view = viewBase.View;
        var viewContext = new ViewContext(context, view, viewBase.ViewData,
                                          viewBase.TempData, sw);
        view.Render(viewContext, sw);
        return sw.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Kirk Woll I've added code to my answer, assuming you have a ViewResultBase object and a ControllerContext object.

Answer (score -1):

Create a controller that renders the html view as you want it to look.  Don't include anything in the html of the view that you don't want in the string

```
public ActionResult HtmlView()
{
     return View();
}


public static string GetContent(string templatePath,  string queryString = "")
    {
        bool isLocal = false;


        if (HttpContext.Current != null)
            isLocal = HttpContext.Current.Request.IsLocal;

        try
        {
            var objWebClient = new System.Net.WebClient();
            byte[] requestedHtml;

            if (isLocal)
            {

                string path = "http://" + HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_NAME"] + ":" +
                              HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_PORT"] + templatePath +
                              queryString;
                requestedHtml = objWebClient.DownloadData(path);
            }
            else
            {
                requestedHtml = objWebClient.DownloadData("http://" + HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_NAME"] + templatePath + queryString);
            }
            var utf8 = new UTF8Encoding();

            return utf8.GetString(requestedHtml).Replace(Environment.NewLine, "");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return "";
        }
    }
```

In your code you can then call

```
string newString = GetContent("/Controller/HtmlView");
```

Comment: This solution introduces an insane amount of overhead, going through the entire HTTP stack twice over.  It should be possible to do this all-at-once, without having to literally download the content over the wire.